# How can I tune memory setting for apache spark 1.5.0?

Tags: apache-spark, memory, garbage-collection, jvm

How can I adjust the in-heap and off-heap memory for application running on spark 1.5.0? By using `-XX+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps`, I noticed that in GC reports retrieved from the file `$SPARK_HOME/work/application_id/stdout`, JVM keeps on GC in about every 1 minute. Though 50g executor memory is allocated via `--executor-memory 50g` option and various `--conf spark.storage.memoryFranction` value, PSYoungGen region always occupied 30% of (PSYoungGen+ParOldGen). PSPermGen always stays in the value aroud 54,272KB with 99% usage.

What I have tried:

1. `spark.executor.extraJavaOptions='-XX:Xms50g -XX:Xmx50g -XX:PermSize=8g'` doesn't work, though loads of blogs ensures this setting works.
2. JAVA_OPTS setting in both `spark-env.sh` and `spark-default.conf` doesn't work

With no explicit in-heap and off-heap memory setting in spark 1.5.0, what's the solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

> JVM keeps on GC in about every 1 minute

Since you haven't posted any actual data, only your own analysis of the data, I cannot say for certain, but generally speaking 1 GC event per minute is perfectly normal, quite good even. So there is no tuning required.